# Migrating portlets to Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, portlet

I have been assigned to restructure an existing portlet application which is based on jboss portal & spring portlets to spring web mvc. Has anyone faced with this situation before? I did find several post on going from web mvc to portlets though but nothing on portlets to web mvc.

Is there a cleaner approach on handling this migration? Is it even possible without involving a huge re-writing of code? The portlets looks simple and does not seems to have too many methods or complex code. I would appreciate any directions or pointers on this.

How to handle the actionRequest and RenderRequest method conversion? Would there be two methods which would be GET and POST or can it be handled in just one method?

Thanks

Comment: What problems have you faced ? Is there something that you can't migrate ?

Comment: @reos - I started with removing the portlets and portals jars and changing the ActionRequest/RenderRequest etc with the servletRequest and so on.But there are still so much code that I cant seem to figure out the alternative in web mvc. Like the usage of PortletUtils and also how to provide configuration for application startup like DB setup and other preference which were in the portal.

Comment: You can add that to your question, the current code and what you think it will be in spring mvc, so people can read and answer your question. You need to be more specific, probably it's better to open one question per each problem that you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my answer based on the research that I have done so far. There is no set of rules for this conversion but the basic start point would be to change the portlets classes to servlets or controller. Removing the portal/portlet dependency from the java classes and jsp one by one.
Spring mvc servlets provide similar functionality to the spring mvc portlets so the back end conversion is not that tough, changing the jsp can be little bothersome but using the jstl, spring tags , these can be converted easily. I creates some include jsp and scripts to carry the common styling,javascripts,css etc which portal used to insert. So far, I have changed a major portion of the project and it seems to be working.

Comment: Hey @Karma . Could you please post here some examples of the classes before and after refactoring? It would be very helpful for me, cause I am facing the similar challenge with migrating from Liferay portlets to Spring MVC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @troger19 , Sorry I don't have access to that anymore but I will check if I can find something.